# Adding Search to Responsive Menu Module

Tags: 7, routes, search, theming

I'm trying to set up responsive menu module (https://drupal.org/project/responsive_menus) and add an advanced search inside of it. I've been unable to get the advanced search to show up in the responsive menu. I am using the codrops' Google Nexus* theme and Drupal 7.

If its not possible to add search inside Responsive Menu, or if there is an alternative module or solution I am open to that as well. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Can you make a "feature request" over on drupal.org about this?
https://drupal.org/node/add/project-issue/responsive_menus

It doesn't have a way to do anything other than the left-side vertical menu currently.  I'd like the Google Nexus style to be able to use the top horizontal area as well.